# Losing mouse cursor on external monitor with 10.13.4

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mouse

I upgraded from 10.13.3 to 10.13.4. The mouse works on the built-in screen but not on an external monitor. A PRAM reset as in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4142250) did nothing. Increasing the size of the cursor as in [this bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47076) shows the mouse pointer but not the I-beam cursor (text cursor), then increasing the size even more shows both cursors. Confusingly, a Quicktime recording of these changes shows the cursor always present, and always the same size.

I am using Dell U2414H. Any fixes better than this work-around?

I add below screenshots for the cursor size when neither pointer appears, when only the mouse pointer appears, and when both mouse pointer and I-beam pointer appear.
[image: Missing both cursors]
[image: Missing I-beam cursor]
[image: Both cursors show]